# C++ templates and static members - definition in the header

Tags: c++, templates, static-members

Consider the following construct:

```
//! Templated singleton.
/*!
    Template wrapper enforcing the singleton behavior.
*/
template <class T>
class TSingleton
{
private:    
    //! Singleton instance pointer.
    static T* instance;
    //! private constructor.
    TSingleton() { }
    //! private empty copy constructor.
    TSingleton(const TSingleton<T>& sourceObject) {}

public:
    //! Static singleton instance getter.
    static T* GetInstance()
    {
        if (instance == 0)
            instance = new T();
        return instance;
    }

};

template <class T> T* TSingleton<T>::instance = 0;
```

This template class and the definition of the static instance are written in the same header file. For a non-template class, this *causes a link-time error due to multiple symbols being defined for the instance static member*. It seems intuitive for this to happen with templates as well, thus one must separate the definition and put it in a .cpp file. But templates are usually declared and defined in header-like files. ***What is it that allows this syntax to be valid and functional for template classes?***

There a [wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/One_definition_rule) link on this, but it does not provide a clear explanation on what happens in case of template classes.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

This works because `[basic.def.odr]/5` explicitly allowed templates to be duplicated:

> There can be more than one definition of a class type (Clause 9), enumeration type (7.2), inline function with external linkage (7.1.2), class template (Clause 14), non-static function template (14.5.6), static data member of a class template (14.5.1.3), member function of a class template (14.5.1.1), or template specialization for which some template parameters are not specified (14.7, 14.5.5) in a program provided that each definition appears in a different translation unit, and provided the definitions satisfy the following requirements. ...

The requirements are quite lengthy, so I won't duplicate them here, but essentially they state that each duplicate definition must be identical (otherwise the program has undefined behaviour).